# Sinatra asset pipeline - can't use link to precompiled css

Tags: css, ruby, sass, sinatra, asset-pipeline

Referenced here https://github.com/kalasjocke/sinatra-asset-pipeline/issues/42

Hi,

I can't make it work in production, whereas it works ok in development

When I deploy in production it does precompile but the CSS are not loaded.
The JS load ok, but no CSS.
Thus I have a html page with some JS, but NO images, NO CSS.

This is how my assets are organized:

[image: capture d ecran 2014-11-26 a 15 12 42]

In local dev env, the assets are precompiled in public/assets/ (with `rake assets:precompile`)
[image: capture d ecran 2014-11-26 a 15 15 59]

In Prod env, the capistrano task is configured this way:

```
  after 'deploy:finishing', :finalize_update do
    on roles(:web), in: :sequence do
      execute(:chmod, '-R g+w', release_path) if fetch(:group_writable, true)

      within release_path do
        execute :rake, "assets:precompile RACK_ENV=production"
        execute :rake, "assets:clean RACK_ENV=production"
      end
    end
  end
```

Sinatra app (let say myapp.rb)

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'sass'
require 'compass'
require 'bootstrap-sass'
require 'sinatra/asset_pipeline'

Bundler.require

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :assets_prefix, %w(assets vendor/assets)
  set :assets_precompile, %w(app.js app.css *.png *.jpg *.svg *.eot *.ttf *.woff)
  register Sinatra::AssetPipeline

  ...
```

app.css

```
*= require application
```

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
...
...
@import "layout";
```

Layout:

```
%link{ href: '/assets/application.css', rel: 'stylesheet' }

...

%script{ src:'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'}
%script{ src: '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' }
%script{ src: '/assets/app.js' }
```

Rakefile:

```
require 'sinatra/asset_pipeline/task'
require './lib/myapp'
Sinatra::AssetPipeline::Task.define! Novagile
```

Am I missing something simple and obvious or is it a vicious config trick ? :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm not sure what did the trick:

I removed `gem 'sass' from`from the Gemfile (compass is still there)

I used sprockets helpers and never `ActionView::Helpers` (like stylesheet_link_tag or stylesheet_tag)

I had a small issue with compass (generated sprites) and sprockets (renaming thoses files before or after) but now everythin works ok...

compass solved with `generated_images_dir`compass config option with a value of the directory to place the generated sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what exactly goes wrong. Definitely source to your layout or views are missed.
Please take a look on [working example](https://gist.github.com/jeffreyiacono/1772989). I can only guess, you have to handle environment (`production` or `development`) by yourself. I example above there is the [view helper](https://gist.github.com/jeffreyiacono/1772989#file-asset_helpers-rb), you may be interested in.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't change a thing :( The helper always generate a <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application.css"> when I believe it should be referenced with a trailing hash/token from compilation. 

I've tried simple direct access, here it's = stylesheet_tag '/assets/application.css' and other helpers doesn't help either.

Tried on dedicated server and heroku, same result, no CSS. Still works in dev.

Comment: God comment are ugly.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your application in production mode? Sorry, for asking that, but according your comment, such behavior is very strange.

Comment: Add some debug puts and the environment variables are OK both in staging and production.        
After some tests the custom JS does not load, it was the CDN one wich is ok that made me thought JS loaded.
Compilation still ok but still no CSS.
When I hard-access to the compiled css it is here.
It is juste the helper that doesn't go get it ! :(